# java card - how off card installataion working

Tags: javacard

I read about there is an off card installation program which actually  triggering the JRE installation in JAVA Card. I read it in https://books.google.co.in/books?id=4WDj4H6pT50C&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=java+card+runtime+environment+install&source=bl&ots=6lSi7Nvh4b&sig=uw3TiWe6Uvk0kl6nCRMlh3IeBnc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2gLKVOe6NYOumAXz0IHoAg&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=java%20card%20runtime%20environment%20install&f=false

I did not find any other better source. Could anybody pls tell how exactly this happening? who is installing the off card installation program? Does the jdk in the terminal/computer contain this off-card installation program?

Answer (score 1):

The **JavaCard Virtual Machine (JCVM)** and **JavaCard Runtime Environment (JCRE)** are runnning inside the javacard. It is part of the operating system. What you are installing using the off-card installation program is the **JavaCard Application** which is called by **Applet**.

After you can get the **CAP file** of your Applet, you can run the **off-card installation program** to download it into your javacard. The program is included in the **JavaCard Development Kit** which can be downloaded from Oracle site. Some programs that are more convenience to use than the kit are listed as follow:

1. [jcmanager](https://github.com/martinpaljak/jcManager), opensource, has been replaced by GlobalPlatformPro
2. [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro), opensource
3. [GPShell](http://sourceforge.net/p/globalplatform/wiki/GPShell/), opensource
4. JCOP plugin for Eclipse from NXP (not free)
5. Gemalto Developer Suite (not free)